# Server side output encoding from html page (not jsp) to prevent XSS

Tags: javascript, encoding, xss, server-side

I have an application with reflected XSS vulnerability caused by an unvalidated url. I want to provide atleast output encoding in the client side. I have access to modify only the front end pages which are in html and js. I do not have access to backend application code , so I cannot use UrlEncoder.encode at server side. 
My question is how can I call server-side encoding from client side forms. 
I know in jsp I can write
<@page import=org.owaps.esapi.*
var url = <%=Esapi.Encoderr.encodetoUrl(vulnerableUrl) =%>

But since my webpage is not jsp , but html+js , how can i call a server-side encoding function?

Comment: You need to provide more information. How does the vulnerability appear? How is the user put into the page?

Comment: HI Erlend. The vulnerability happens because the backend application which i connect to, does not validate the redirection url and sends back to the front end pages to set as redirect url , like document.forms[0].redirect.value = malcious url. An attacker is able to come and modify the url and add <script> alert (''); </script> . When the developer can edit only the logon pages (which is in html+js) , but cannot write some code in server side, is there a way to put some code in the html+js to do output encoding which will prevent reflected xss like above , and cannot be bypassed.

Comment: @Erlend. The vulnerability happens because the backend application which i connect to, does not validate the redirection url and sends back to the front end pages to set as redirect url , like document.forms[0].redirect.value = malcious url. An attacker is able add alert ('');.

Comment: @Erlend: When the developer can edit only the logon pages(which is in html+js), but cannot write some code in server side, is there a way to put some code in the html+js to do output encoding which will prevent reflected xss like above. will document.forms[0].redirect.value = encodeURI(malcious url) work? since encodeURI is a js function,can it be bypassed. so what's a solution to fix this from client side? if it was jsp i could have added some server side validation code. what are my options in pure html and js?

Answer (score 2):

Given the information you provided I would say no, it's probably not possible.

Let's say you add:
document.forms[0].redirect.value = encodeURI(malcious url)

Now the attacker comes along and sends in:

```
"); alert("xss")
```

The problem is that the malicious data is already in the page when the client script runs, and would already have altered the layout and contexts of the page.

I think there would be a better chance of fixing this by employing a WAF like mod_security to limit the prossible values that can enter the app, then trying to fix it client side. Though actually fixing the problem server side is the best option.